# Set Referrer Information on Rails Redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-referer, http-redirect

I'm working on a Rails app that redirects users from my Rails app to an outside site. I'd like to be able to track those users that arrived from my Rails app to that site, but on Google Analytics all of those referrals show up as "Direct" instead of from my domain.

Is there any reason for this? Can I set something differently so it doesn't show up as direct traffic?

I tried doing this:

```
request.env['HTTP_REFERRER'] = 'http://www.mysite.com'
```

But it didn't seem to work. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: did you resolve this problem? I think that you can ignore or flag referring sites so that it treats them differently from 'direct' traffic.

Comment: no never resolved it. what do you mean? I would I do that

Comment: You can tell google analytics to ignore certain ip addressses or ranges. I imagined it might be able to do the same for referrers.